# How switch port 8080 to port 80 in Nginx Bitnami

Tags: php, nginx, bitnami

I am using Nginx Bitnami stack on my local Mac. Nginx works on port 8080. How can change port 8080 to port 80. It works localhost:8080 but i need localhost.
I am using this config.

```html
    # HTTP server

    server {
        listen       8080;
        server_name  localhost;

        location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }

        include "/Applications/nginxstack/nginx/conf/bitnami/phpfastcgi.conf";

        include "/Applications/nginxstack/nginx/conf/bitnami/bitnami-apps-prefix.conf";
    }

    # HTTPS server
    
    server {
       listen       8443;
       server_name  localhost;

       ssl_certificate      server.crt;
       ssl_certificate_key  server.key;

       ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
       ssl_session_timeout  5m;

       ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
       ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

       location / {
           root   html;
           index  index.html index.htm;
       }

       include "/Applications/nginxstack/nginx/conf/bitnami/phpfastcgi.conf";

       include "/Applications/nginxstack/nginx/conf/bitnami/bitnami-apps-prefix.conf";
    }


    include "/Applications/nginxstack/nginx/conf/bitnami/bitnami-apps-vhosts.conf";
```

Answer (score 0):

MAC using the MAMPP or Apache Server By Default. First uninstall MAMPP or Apache Server From MAC OS.

Because Apache server using 80 port for running Web server.

Then Change the port of Nginx to 80

server {

```
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    location / {
        root   html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    include "/Applications/nginxstack/nginx/conf/bitnami/phpfastcgi.conf";

    include "/Applications/nginxstack/nginx/conf/bitnami/bitnami-apps-prefix.conf";
}
```

Reload the Nginx server

I think This will Help you

Comment: I got the solution. The error was i am using Openoffice its running on port 80. Just remove OpenOffice.